# Getting relationship error for a SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, query

I am getting below error.

> Didn't understand relationship 'Invoice_CU__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name.

SOQL:

```
select Actuals__c,(select id,Total_Price__c from Invoice_CU__r) from Sales_Quota__c
```

1. **`Sales_Quota__c`**(master)
2. **`Invoice_CU__c`** (child) has lookup relationship.

Comment: check this post http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/128881/18731 use describe call to check correct relationship name and use that

Comment: Or else refer to your wsdl to get the correct relationship name. It needs the plural form of child here, probably with **s** at the end.

Comment: Super @Ratan
I used below code to get relationship.I was able to figure it out.
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult R = Account.SObjectType.getDescribe();
for (Schema.ChildRelationship cr: R.getChildRelationships()) 
{
  system.debug('====child object==='+cr.getRelationshipName());
}

Correct SOQL will be :
select Id,Actuals__c,(select Id,Total_Price__c from Invoices__r) from Sales_Quota__c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Get All Child objects relationship name.

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult R = Account.SObjectType.getDescribe();
for (Schema.ChildRelationship cr: R.getChildRelationships()) 
{
  system.debug('====child object==='+cr.getRelationshipName());
}
```

Try to run above describe call in developer console and check the debug log and check the correct relationship name for `Invoice_CU__c` object and use it in your soql.

Answer (score 4):

Run this code in developer console and you will get the Child relationship's API Name

```
for (ChildRelationship relationship : SObjectType.Sales_Quota__c.getChildRelationships())
    if (relationship.getChildSObject() == Invoice_CU__c.sObjectType)
        system.debug(relationship.getRelationshipName());
```